# Recaptcha validation on localhost php

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am using re-captcha on localhost, It shows up correctly on site but when I am validating the response from user it gives error as -

`object(ReCaptchaResponse)#1 (2) { ["is_valid"]=> bool(false) ["error"]=> string(22) "invalid-request-cookie" }`

Please help me what should I do? 
Also my system is behind proxy server.

Code -

-To render captcha - 
`echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);`

Reading captcha -

```
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468433/google-recaptcha-saysinvalid-request-cookie

Comment: Hi Halayem, I am essentially doing the same mentioned on that link but its not working